# Resize window Automatically without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code works quite fine; if menu-1 is on width > 991 and I display it, it works; but if I resize it to check it media view, it is still set to `display: block` instead of being set to `display: none` that I have to use the toggle btn to display. I want my dropdown to be set to `display: none` if the window size changes. How can I go about that? Please kindly help me with this.

```
let viewpoint = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
     viewpoint = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   },true);
allPage.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
    if(viewpoint <=991){
        backdbtn() 
            if(event.target == productBtn && viewpoint <= 991 ){
                secondbtn() 
                if( menu1.classList.contains('product-d-none')){
                    menu1.classList.remove('product-d-none');
                    backBtn.classList.remove('v-none');
                }
               
            }  if(event.target == backBtn || event.target == allPage){menu1.classList.add('product-d-none'); 
            backBtn.classList.add('v-none')}
          
    } 
       
    if(viewpoint >991){
        secondbtn() 
        if(viewpoint !== 991){ 
        backBtn.classList.add('v-none')}
            if(event.target == productBtn && viewpoint > 991 ){
                secondbtn() 
                if( menu1.classList.contains('product-d-none')){
                    menu1.classList.remove('product-d-none');
                } else{menu1.classList.add('product-d-none');}
                alert('window is less than 991')
            } 
    
            else{menu1.classList.add('product-d-none');}
    }
   });

    

   if(viewpoint > 991){
    secondbtn()
    menu1.classList.add('product-d-none');
    productBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if( menu1.classList.contains('product-d-none')){
            menu1.classList.remove('product-d-none');
            secondbtn()
        } else{menu1.classList.add('product-d-none');}
    });
}
```

Comment: Just because your `viewpoint > 991`, does  not mean the `productBtn.addEventListener('click, ()=>{})` knows that the page is resized. Your original test to assign the Event, is on load. Why assign to the Entire page anyways when you really just want to click that `productBtn`? What's the point of `if(viewpoint !== 991)`, and `viewpoint > 991` again later, when the test that guarantees those will be true was already performed above, inside `if(viewpoint >991){`?

Comment: Please, what am i suppose to do now to rectify it?